# In the Django generic detail view where does context's index come from?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In the example below where does context's index 'book_list' comes from, if is arbitrary what is the naming convention?

```
class PublisherDetail(DetailView):

model = Publisher

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(PublisherDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
    return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example, the variable name `book_list` is arbitrary. You could use `books` or anything else you like instead.

Using `book_list` is consistent with the `ListView`, which makes the list available in the template context as `<lowercase model name>_list` . See the docs on [making friendly template contexts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention you're referring to (`_list`) is based on the `ListView`'s `template_name_suffix`. That inherits from [MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.list/MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin/).

In practice if you use a `ListView` like this one based on your example:

```
class PublisherList(ListView):

    model = Publisher
```

...you would able to refer to `publisher_list` in your template for the queryset of all publishers.

In your example you're including a list of all the books in your database using the same naming convention, but you could call that context variable (`book_list`) anything you wanted.